# why text change listener function called multiple time without text change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have `TextFormField` with a text change listener attached to it. But listener function called even when I click on the text field and sometimes even I clicked outside the text field. I'm using flutter 2.5.2 version.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: SearchView(),
  ));
}

class SearchView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SearchView> createState() => _SearchViewState();
}

class _SearchViewState extends State<SearchView> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  final rng = new Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.textController.addListener(this._onTextChanged);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onTextChanged() {
    print('text changed listener called ${rng.nextDouble()}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Brand'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: this.textController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79982). It's because the listener actually is not only listening for **text changes**, but also for **focus changes**.

What you can do to prevent this and only listen for text changes is using the `onChanged()` method on the TextFormField like this:

```
TextFormField(
    onChanged: (String newText) => print('$newText'),
),
```